# Finding power using work as $Fd$ or as change in energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, work, power

This is a question I had been given a few years ago and I have found two different answers depending on how I find work. If I use $W=Fd$ vs $W=E_f-E_i$, I get two separate answers. I must be missing some assumption. This is for grade 11 Physics.

A man is lowering a 38 kg pail of nails down 15 m to the ground by a rope. He does not want the pail to hit the ground in free fall but he is not strong enough to completely stop it. Even though the pail starts at rest, when it hits the ground it is moving at 8.3 m/s. Assume no friction or air resistance.  If the whole process takes 2.5 minutes, what was the power output of the man?

Answer 1

$$P=\frac{Ef-Ei}{t}$$
$$P=\frac{1/2mv^2-mgh}{t}$$
$$P=\frac{1/2*38*8.3^2-38*9.81*15}{150}$$
$$P=-29W$$

Answer 2

$$Acceleration=\frac{8.3}{150}$$
$$a=0.055...$$

$$F_{net}=Fg-Fa$$

$$F_a=F_g-F_{net}$$

$$F_a=mg-ma$$

$$F_a=370.677...$$

Now,

$$P=\frac{F_a*d}{t}$$

$$P=\frac{370.677..*15}{150}$$

$$P=-37W$$

Comment: Show us how you got two different answers

Comment: sorry I should have done that sooner

Comment: I can't follow the reasoning in your second answer, but the first one seems correct.

Comment: Why are you assuming a constant acceleration? This isn't a constant acceleration process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have assumed the acceleration was constant and then calculated it using:

$$ a = \frac{v_{final} - v_{initial}}{time} = \frac{8.3}{150} = 0.0553~\text{m/s}^2 $$

But suppose we calculate the distance that the bucket would have moved if the acceleration had this value. That distance is:

$$ s = ut + \tfrac12 at^2 = \tfrac12 \times 0.0553 \times 150^2 = 623~\text{m} $$

But the bucket only moved $15$ metres, so the conclusion is that the acceleration cannot have been constant. And if the acceleration does vary with time the data you have been given is not enough for you to calculate this variation. That means you cannot work out the net force on the bucket and therefore you cannot use that net force to calculate the work done.